# Android NDK GNU Ld does not find symbols but LLD 9.0.9 does

Tags: android-ndk, clang, llvm, linker-errors, ld

I am compiling a third party lib (libstrophe) with NDK21 Toolchain. For Android 64 Bit target it fails with following error if GNU Linker is used:

```
$ /opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang -I. -I/home/sandro/Projects/libstrophe_ref/openssl/include -I/home/sandro/Projects/libstrophe_ref/libxml2/include -Werror -g -o examples/.libs/active examples/examples_active-active.o  -L../openssl/android_aarch64_ndk21 -L../libxml2/android_aarch64_ndk21 ./.libs/libstrophe.so -L/home/sandro/Projects/libstrophe_ref/temp_build/lib -v
Android (7019983 based on r365631c3) clang version 9.0.9 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project a2a1e703c0edb03ba29944e529ccbf457742737b) (based on LLVM 9.0.9svn)
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-android21
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x
Selected GCC installation: /opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld" -pie -z noexecstack -EL --fix-cortex-a53-843419 --warn-shared-textrel -z now -z relro -z max-page-size=4096 --hash-style=gnu --hash-style=both --enable-new-dtags --eh-frame-hdr -m aarch64linux -dynamic-linker /system/bin/linker64 -o examples/.libs/active /opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/21/crtbegin_dynamic.o -L../openssl/android_aarch64_ndk21 -L../libxml2/android_aarch64_ndk21 -L/home/sandro/Projects/libstrophe_ref/temp_build/lib -L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.9/lib/linux/aarch64 -L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x -L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/lib/../lib64 -L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/21 -L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android -L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/lib -L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib examples/examples_active-active.o ./.libs/libstrophe.so -lgcc -ldl -lc -lgcc -ldl /opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/21/crtend_android.o
/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: libssl_1_1.so, needed by ./.libs/libstrophe.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto_1_1.so, needed by ./.libs/libstrophe.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: libxml2.so, needed by ./.libs/libstrophe.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `xmlParseChunk@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_write@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `xmlCreatePushParserCtxt@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_pending@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_read@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_free@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeParserCtxt@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_error@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_connect@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_verify@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_free@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_new@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
./.libs/libstrophe.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I force to use clang LLD it is working fine (`-fuse-ld=lld`):

```
$ /opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang
-I. -I/home/sandro/Projects/libstrophe_ref/openssl/include -I/home/sandro/Projects/libstrophe_ref/libxml2/include -Werror -g -o examples/.libs/active examples/examples_active-active.o 
-L../openssl/android_aarch64_ndk21 -L../libxml2/android_aarch64_ndk21 ./.libs/libstrophe.so
-L/home/sandro/Projects/libstrophe_ref/temp_build/lib -fuse-ld=lld -v Android (7019983 based on r365631c3) clang version 9.0.9 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project a2a1e703c0edb03ba29944e529ccbf457742737b) (based on LLVM 9.0.9svn) Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-android21 Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin Found candidate GCC installation: /opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x Selected GCC installation: /opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x Candidate multilib: .;@m64 Selected multilib: .;@m64  "/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/ld.lld"
-pie -z noexecstack -EL --fix-cortex-a53-843419 --warn-shared-textrel -z now -z relro -z max-page-size=4096 --hash-style=gnu --hash-style=both --enable-new-dtags --eh-frame-hdr -m aarch64linux -dynamic-linker /system/bin/linker64 -o examples/.libs/active /opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/21/crtbegin_dynamic.o -L../openssl/android_aarch64_ndk21 -L../libxml2/android_aarch64_ndk21 -L/home/sandro/Projects/libstrophe_ref/temp_build/lib -L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.9/lib/linux/aarch64
-L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x
-L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/lib/../lib64
-L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/21
-L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android
-L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/lib
-L/opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib examples/examples_active-active.o ./.libs/libstrophe.so -lgcc -ldl -lc
-lgcc -ldl /opt/Android/android-ndk-r21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/21/crtend_android.o
```

**Question**

What is the reason why GNU Linker does not found the object references but LDD Clang Linker does?

If I compile for Android 32 Bit target it is also working with GNU linker.